# Python の gkeepapi モジュールで Google Keep に画像を投稿する事は可能か？

Tags: python, google-api

Python の [gkeepapi](https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi) モジュールを使い、Google Keep に画像を投稿をしたいと考えています。

ドキュメントを読む限り、元々ある画像は取得できても、投稿については触れられてませんでした。調べても gkeepapi で画像投稿してるといった記事は見つかりませんでした。

現在は Selenium を使って画像を投稿してますが、バックグラウンドで処理したいです。

どなたか経験のある方がいらっしゃったらご教授いただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

#### 短い回答

できません。

#### 長い回答

`gkeepapi` のドキュメント及びソースコードを確認しましたが、画像アップロードの方法はありませんでした。
[Welcome to gkeepapi’s documentation! — gkeepapi 0.13.6 documentation](https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
[gkeepapi/node.py at master · kiwiz/gkeepapi · GitHub](https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi/blob/master/gkeepapi/node.py)

また、Google Keep APIでも画像のダウンロードは可能ですが、アップロードは不可能そうです。

- https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/v1/notes#Note

  - `title` と `body` 以外がOutput only（書き込み不可）と明記されている
- https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/v1/media

  - 添付ファイルは、downloadしかできない

ですので、結論としては **`gkeepapi` 及び `Google Keep API` では画像の投稿ができない** という形です。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。
やはりできないのですね。 別の方法で試します。
ありがとうございました。